# Tensorflow C library "available" for Windows?

Tags: tensorflow

The [release notes for tensorflow 1.2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.2.0) says that

> - TensorFlow C library now available for Windows.

Nice. However the [page dedicated to the C API](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c) on tensorflow's web site gives instructions for Linux and Mac OS X only.

What do the authors means when they say a Windows C library is "*available*", especially when they [do not officially support building from sources on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)? Is there a precompiled binary somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation hasn't been updated yet, although in the meantime you can download the library here:

> <sub>**https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.2.0.zip**</sub>

↳ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10817

Comment: I can't use this in Visual Studio without a .lib file, where is it? I tried to build it from source, but I've failed.

Comment: @sebesbal Probably too late for you, but this guide never failed me: https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/

Comment: **Version 1.4 is available**: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.2.0.zip

Answer (score 2):

Remark, that there are newer versions of the tensorflow c api for windows. If you change the version number at the end of the URL, you can download the latest versions. Current is:

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.9.0.zip

Answer (score 1):

you can use pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib as well. 
then you get cpu and gpu usage, too.

the things you need are

- c_api.h which you can get [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.5.0.zip)
- pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib from your python installation
- _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd from your python installation

Answer (score 1):

All "official" builds are listed here: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow
(also can be downloaded from there )