# Cabal: missing dependency on foreign C library

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have been trying to install the tensorflow/haskell package on my Windows machine.

However, both while installing with stack and cabal, I keep running into this error:

```
Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing C library: tensorflow
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

According to the Tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c
, the C package for Tensorflow only runs on Unix machines. I am not sure if this is a dead end or if there is some workaround.

I am not experienced with linking libraries or with cabal, and would appreciate some assistance.

Using Cabal, I've included the following .cabal file in my directory:

```
cabal-version: >= 1.2 
Executable hax 
Includes: c_api.h 
Extra-libraries: tensorflow
```

but I still receive the errors: `cabal.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library: * Missing C library: tensorflow The exception was: user error (Using 'build-type: Custom' but there is no Setup.hs or Setup.lhs script.)`

Comment: The page you linked doesn't have explicit Windows instructions, but certainly it's [designed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/61c0b39011671628ee85c2b49bc8845520018aa2/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L75) to be built on Windows as well. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib/cmake) is such a build.

Comment: I've found what is supposed to be the C library here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682845/tensorflow-c-library-available-for-windows but I'm not sure what to tell cabal what to do with it

Comment: You can pass the flag `--extra-lib-dirs=<..>` to cabal (stack has a corresponding field which can be placed in the config file). I don't know this will be enough; you may need the `.lib` file as well as the `.dll` (I don't know enough about how GHC links things to know if it'll actually be the case).

Comment: Feel free to edit your question with your attempt - there is not much anyone can do with a single line of an error message in isolation.

Comment: Using Cabal, I've included the following .cabal file in my directory: `cabal-version: >= 1.2
Executable hax
    Includes: c_api.h
    Extra-libraries: tensorflow` but I still receive the errors: 
cabal.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: tensorflow
The exception was:
user error (Using 'build-type: Custom' but there is no Setup.hs or Setup.lhs script.)

Comment: This cabal file would imply that you are trying to write your own Haskell program which depends directly on the `tensorflow` C library. The rest of the question implies you are trying to build the `tensorflow` Haskell library (which are different things!); if you want to use the Haskell bindings, you must depend on the Haskell package, and you don't need to add the transitive foreign dependency to your own cabal file. (The error "(Using 'build-type: Custom' but there is no Setup.hs or Setup.lhs script.)" is completely unrelated to this - see the cabal docs for what `build-type: custom` means)

Comment: Removing everything but the cabal-version, I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You write "According to the Tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c , the C package for Tensorflow only runs on Unix machines. I am not sure if this is a dead end or if there is some workaround."

Indeed, if you don't have the `tensorflow` C package installed on your machine -- because it won't run on it, then you can't find it to bind to it.

There is no work around for that.